# How would I get the command that a member inputed in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently busy building a very modular discord bot and so I am attempting to create a command call that is built from a config file.

I want to be able to have a small amount of code and have the functions be dynamically called depending on what I put into the config file but now I am stuck with not being able to find what the actual command is that the member inputted.

```
STATIC_NAMES = ['rules', 'server']

@commands.command(aliases=STATIC_NAMES)
async def caller_(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed=self.embed_dict["the actual command that the person inputted"])
```

Essentially what I am asking is whether it is possible to get what the actual command was that called the function if you are using aliases for your calls.

Edit:

I know that I am editing this rather quickly but I seem to have found an alright workaround until I can find a better solution.

I am just taking the entire message, cutting out the prefix, splitting it in case there are other arguments passed and then capitalizing that.

```
await ctx.send(embed=self.embed_dict[ctx.message.content[len(PREFIX):].split(' ')[0].capitalize()])
```

Which is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Context.command.name` attributes:

```py
command_name = ctx.command.name
```